# use li element as a button

Tags: html, css, button, html-lists

I have ul elements like below in my html

```
<ul class="nav" id="loadCategories">
  <li class="sub-menu"><a href="#">Search by category</a>
    <ul class="">
      <li><a href="#">Food</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sports</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Personal</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li class="sub-menu"><a href="#">Search by city</a>
     <ul class="">
       <li><a href="#">Mumbai</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Bangalore</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Personal</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>            

</ul>
```

Now I want to use a button just below this `ul`. But when I put something like the code below it breaks.

```
 <input type="button" class="signout_btn" value="Sign Out" id="btnSignOut">Signout</input>
```

So is there any way I can put my button as a `li` element in order to get the exact same look(CSS).

Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bzdqtmkq/) for the same. The button should look like the `ul` element

Comment: Can you please paste your complete css too?

Comment: What breaks? What goes wrong? If it's style, we need your CSS.

Comment: Where exactly you want to put the button? Please a create  a plunk or jsfiddle  that would be helpful to understand your issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the code just add a button in a "li" element and remove bullet.

```
<ul class="nav" id="loadCategories">
   <li class="sub-menu">
      <a href="#">Search by category</a>
      <ul class="">
          <li><a href="#">Food</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sports</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Personal</a></li>
     </ul>
   </li>
   <li class="sub-menu">
         <a href="#">Search by city</a>
         <ul class="">
             <li><a href="#">Mumbai</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Bangalore</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Personal</a></li>
         </ul>
    </li>
   <li class="no-bullet">
       <button type="button" class="signout_btn" id="btnSignOut">Sign Out</button>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Also make the `list-style-type` to none

```
.no-bullet{
   list-style-type: none
 }
```

Here is a fiddle check it out.Hope it helps!! [link](https://jsfiddle.net/sarojsasmal/bzdqtmkq/2/)

Comment: what did you change apart from the `no-bullet` class?

Comment: Wrapped the button inside a `li` element.

Comment: Is it what you wanted or something else ?

Comment: Looks fine in the fiddle but when I use it It looks like this [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/UrAju8l.png)

Comment: It may be due to sub-menu class or something , You can check it. Well you can add a `padding-left` to this if you want to make it aligned

Comment: Yes logically its sort of ugly way to do it. :P 

Thanks anyway

Comment: Did you add `sub-menu` class to the last li ?, I see an arrow, drop down symbol in it. It shouldn't be there.There must be some css class that is the culprit.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `width=100%` and `height=100%` with set parameters for the list?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
<ul class="nav" id="loadCategories">
<li><input type="button" class="signout_btn" value="Sign Out" id="btnSignOut">Signout</li>
  <li class="sub-menu"><a href="#">Search by category</a>
    <ul class="">
      <li><a href="#">Food</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sports</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Personal</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li class="sub-menu"><a href="#">Search by city</a>
     <ul class="">
       <li><a href="#">Mumbai</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Bangalore</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Personal</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>            

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<input>` elements are [empty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Empty_element) (you shouldn't use end tags). I prefer to use `<button>` elements:

```
<button class="signout_btn" id="btnSignOut">Sign Out</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please check with this code?

```
<ul class="nav" id="loadCategories">
        <li class="sub-menu"><a href="#">Search by category</a>
            <ul class="">
                <li><a href="#">Food</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sports</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Personal</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="sub-menu"><a href="#">Search by city</a>
             <ul class="">
               <li><a href="#">Mumbai</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Bangalore</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Personal</a></li>
             </ul>
        </li> 
        <li class="sub-menu"><a href="#"></a>
                <button class="signout_btn" id="btnSignOut" style="background: none;border:none;color: #fff;margin-left: 20px;">Sign Out</button>
        </li>           
    </ul>
```

The output will be: [image]

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code snippet..

```
 <ul class="nav" id="loadCategories">
        <li class="sub-menu"><a href="#">Search by category</a>
                <ul class="">
                    <li><a href="#">Food</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sports</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Personal</a></li>
                </ul>
        </li>

        <li class="sub-menu"><a href="#">Search by city</a>
                <ul class="">
                    <li><a href="#">Mumbai</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Bangalore</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Personal</a></li>
                </ul>
        </li>            

        <input type="button" class="signout_btn" value="Sign Out" id="btnSignOut">
    </ul>
```

CSS:

```
.signout_btn{
text-transform: uppercase;
outline: none;
border: 0;
background-color: #673a9a;
line-height: 40px;
color: #fff;    display: inline-block;
font-size: 16px;
margin: 10px;
cursor: pointer;
```

}

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$( ".menu" ).click(function() {
$('.slide-menu').addClass('active');
$('.slide-wrapper').addClass('active');
});

$( "li.sub-menu" ).click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('act');
  $(this).find('ul').slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: there cannot be anything other than li at ul.