# how to make div clickable instead of putting it inside searchbox in html

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

i have created a searchbox in html using ajax and javascript.
the results are loaded from the database, when the word is typed the word is displayed below, when we click on the displayed word, the word is inserted into the searchbox and nothing happens.

html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>



<head>

   <title></title>

   <!-- Including jQuery is required. -->

   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

   <!-- Including our scripting file. -->

   <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

   <!-- Including CSS file. -->

   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

</head>



<body>

<!-- Search box. -->

   <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Search" />

   <br>



   <br />

   <!-- Suggestions will be displayed in below div. -->

   <div id="display"></div>



</body>



</html>
```

ajax

```html
<?php

//Including Database configuration file.

include "db.php";

//Getting value of "search" variable from "script.js".

if (isset($_POST['search'])) {

//Search box value assigning to $Name variable.

   $Name = $_POST['search'];

//Search query.

   $Query = "SELECT Name FROM search WHERE Name LIKE '%$Name%' LIMIT 5";

//Query execution

   $ExecQuery = MySQLi_query($con, $Query);

//Creating unordered list to display result.

   echo '

<ul>

   ';

   //Fetching result from database.

   while ($Result = MySQLi_fetch_array($ExecQuery)) {

       ?>

   <!-- Creating unordered list items.

        Calling javascript function named as "fill" found in "script.js" file.

        By passing fetched result as parameter. -->

   <li onclick='fill("<?php echo $Result['Name']; ?>")'>

   <a>

   <!-- Assigning searched result in "Search box" in "search.php" file. -->

       <?php echo $Result['Name']; ?>

   </li></a>

   <!-- Below php code is just for closing parenthesis. Don't be confused. -->

   <?php

}}


?>

</ul>
```

javascript

```html
//Getting value from "ajax.php".

function fill(Value) {

   //Assigning value to "search" div in "search.php" file.

   $('#search').val(Value);

   //Hiding "display" div in "search.php" file.

   $('#display').hide();

}

$(document).ready(function() {

   //On pressing a key on "Search box" in "search.php" file. This function will be called.

   $("#search").keyup(function() {

       //Assigning search box value to javascript variable named as "name".

       var name = $('#search').val();

       //Validating, if "name" is empty.

       if (name == "") {

           //Assigning empty value to "display" div in "search.php" file.

           $("#display").html("");

       }

       //If name is not empty.

       else {

           //AJAX is called.

           $.ajax({

               //AJAX type is "Post".

               type: "POST",

               //Data will be sent to "ajax.php".

               url: "ajax.php",

               //Data, that will be sent to "ajax.php".

               data: {

                   //Assigning value of "name" into "search" variable.

                   search: name

               },

               //If result found, this funtion will be called.

               success: function(html) {

                   //Assigning result to "display" div in "search.php" file.

                   $("#display").html(html).show();

               }

           });

       }

   });

});
```

the searchbox is like below when we start searching

[image]
and when we click any word displayed for example the 2nd word, it will be inserted to the searchbox like below:

[image]

i want to make the word clickable, instead of isnerting it into the searchbox. can anyone edit my code please

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just your text inside the `<li>`, put it into a `<a>` tag.

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#">David Copperfield</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Cristiano Ronaldo</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Then attach your `onclick` event to the link.

Comment: See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41821877/use-li-element-as-a-button)